# Save info in a form before Post

Tags: javascript, php, forms, paypal

I am creating a [registration form](http://alesh.com/projects/summer-camp/2015.html) that uses JavaScript to calculate an amount and uses `method="post"` to redirect the user to PayPal to complete the transaction. The piece I'm missing is some way to capture the information before sending them off to pay. Ideally emailing a copy of the information or even saving to a text file on the server.

I'm kind of a n00b here, so while I realize it's possible to post to my own PHP script and have that redirect them to PayPal, I'm not sure I'd be able to figure out all the pieces in that workflow. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can save your form values into a database and then send it to paypal but I need your html to give you appropriate PHP code.

Comment: Sure, it's right here: 

view-source:http://alesh.com/projects/summer-camp/2015.html

The form begins at line 198. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful, if you're saving credit card information you need to make sure you are not breaking the law and/or have the necessary credentials (e.g. PCI compliance)

Paypal also has a function where it will notify a URL, that you specify, when the transaction has been processed. It will give you a summary of the transaction. You can then use that to perform post-payment operations, e.g. change your order status, send email...etc.

Comment: No no -- all the payment info is handled by PayPal. My form collects their name, address etc., plus the list of sessions and options they're signing up for. I pass the dollar amount to PayPal, but I need an easy way to capture the other info first.

Comment: Then you need to submit to PayPal *after* your server stores the information that you need. This requires server-side coding. What you need to do then, is to split your thinking into 2 parts: 1) Save information 2) Submit to paypal. Do each part separately, they are different problems entirely.